# Why isn't my container covering the full width of the screen?

Tags: react-native

[image: screenshot of the relevant view]

I'm in the process of making my views responsive. At the moment I am trying to get the component with the green background to cover the full width of the screen.

Here is the code for the component with the green background:

```
container: {
    // backgroundColor: '#14172B',
    backgroundColor: 'green',
    // width: '100%'
  }
```

...and here is the code for the singular HR/ACT/BPM/TEMP components

```
  wrapper: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
    backgroundColor: '#1B1E34',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    paddingHorizontal: 5,
    paddingVertical: 5,
    borderRadius: 5,
    marginHorizontal: 10,
    marginVertical: 5,
    width: deviceWidth * 0.4,
    height: deviceHeight * 0.08
  }
```

...and, finally, here is the code for the complete component that is rendered in the view

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    // backgroundColor: '#14172B',
    backgroundColor: 'orange',
    height: Dimensions.get('screen').height * 0.1,
    width: screenWidth,
    // flex: 1,
    // height: '20%',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    flexWrap: 'wrap'
  }
})
```

Thank you all!

Comment: if you want your width to be the full width of the screen, should you not just set the width to 100% rather than screenWidth * 0.4?  If that's not the problem, the please could you make a [mcve] with your compiled html and css (as this seems to be more of a css problem rather than a react problem)

Comment: share your html code or pls make https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qqb2p8

Comment: @Pete that relates to the individual HR/ACT/TEMP/RESP components, rather than the full container parent, so your solution doesn't work in this case

Comment: Well then it's impossible to tell what it refers to from the amount of code supplied and no html, please see the second part of my above comment

Answer (score 0):

You can try this since your code is not available fully.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Create four equal columns that floats next to each other */
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 48%;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 300px; /* Should be removed. Only for demonstration */
  margin:1%;
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Equal Columns</h2>

<div class="row">
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;">
    <h2>Column 1</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#bbb;">
    <h2>Column 2</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;">
    <h2>Column 1</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#bbb;">
    <h2>Column 2</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```